# Data Annotation unable to get Error message from ModelSate other than Required

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I am using `Data Annotation` for server side validation and from the client i send the data to the controller and then from `ModelState` i am trying to get the `ErrorMessage`.

**My code.**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Order ID cannot be null")]
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "OrderID must be greater than 0.")]
    public int OrderID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Required]//(ErrorMessage = "Customer ID cannot be null")]
    [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "CustomerID must be 5 characters.")]
    public string CustomerID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

**My controller code**

```
public ActionResult Validate(EditableOrder order)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            List<string> errorlist = new List<string>();
            foreach (ModelState modelState in ModelState.Values)
            {
                foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors)
                {
                    errorlist.Add(error.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            return Content(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(errorlist));
        }
        return Content("true");
    }
```

**My Script code.**

```
 var record = args.data;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Inlineform/Validate",
            type: "POST",
            data: record,
            success: function (data) {
                var errorlist = JSON.parse(data);
                var i;
                if (errorlist.length)
                {
                    args.cancel = true;
                    var str="";
                    $.each(errorlist,function(index,error){
                        str+="<tr><td>"+error+"</td></tr>";
                    });
                    $("#ErrorList").html("<table>"+str+"</table>");
                }
            }
```

When the request is made to the action `Validate` I can able to bind it with the `EditableOrder` and in ModelState i only getting the `ErrorMessage` of `Required` and not `Range` or `StringLength`.

What goes wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To make validation effective for MVC2, you have to place the following code on the page(s) containing the fields that need to be validated:

```
    <script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    ...
    @Html.EnableClientValidation();
```

Also, using StringLength will not work for the minimum length.  The default adapter for StringLength in MVC is:

```
    public class StringLengthAttributeAdapter : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<StringLengthAttribute>
    {
      public StringLengthAttributeAdapter(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, StringLengthAttribute attribute): base(metadata, context, attribute)
      {}
    public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
      {
        return new[] { new ModelClientValidationStringLengthRule(ErrorMessage, 0, Attribute.MaximumLength) };
      }
    }
```

Someone had an off day at Microsoft when this code was written.

You can override the StringLength adapter to make it function normally by using:

```
    public class StringLengthAttributeAdapter : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<StringLengthAttribute>
    {
      public StringLengthAttributeAdapter(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, StringLengthAttribute attribute): base(metadata, context, attribute)
      {}
    public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
      {
        return new[] { new ModelClientValidationStringLengthRule(ErrorMessage, Attribute.MinimumLength, Attribute.MaximumLength) };
      }
    }
```

Finally, place this code into your global.asax.cs file:

```
    DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(StringLengthAttribute), typeof(MVCWebPractice.Models.StringLengthAttributeAdapter));
```

This fixes the problems with StringLength.  You should not need to create any client-side javascript to implement any of this.

To print a summary of errors in the specific section, place this is the appropriate place on your view:

```
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(false) %>
```

You need to set the flag to false to display errors related to property values.  I am assuming this is what you are trying to do with the custom javascript code.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, you can just use Html.ValidationSummary() and get the same result.  The flag is optional and is used primarily when you don't want to display property errors.